# " I know him to speak to." What does this mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, parsing

I know him / to speak **"to"**.

1. What is **"to"**'s object? speak to whom?
2. Who is the subject of "to speak"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you know the person well enough to speak to them if you pass them in the street, but no better than that, i.e. they are an acquaintance rather than a friend.

So 'I' is the subject and 'him' the object. (Of course, it's assumed that he will answer you!)

Comment: ok, if so, know him (to be ill) is different from "to speak to" because "because he is ill" is different from "I speak to": he and I are different subject in "to-infinitive"

Comment: Yes, it's a different construction from _I know him to be [adjective]_, which means _I know that he is [adjective]_.